# How to make car turn 90 degrees?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I have an elegoo car model and am trying to make it turn 90 degrees whenever it gets to a 90 degree turn. This model has line tracing and it works fine on curved surfaces but doesn't work so on 90 degree turns.

```
    /Line Tracking IO define
#define LT_R !digitalRead(10)//connected to pin 10. Value is inverted
#define LT_M !digitalRead(4)
#define LT_L !digitalRead(2)
 
#define ENA 5//input to enable motor A. Controls speed
#define ENB 6//input to enable motor B
#define IN1 7//Control spinning direction of motor A. If one of them is high motor spin(an OR gate)
#define IN2 8//Same motor A
#define IN3 9//3 and 4 are for motor B
#define IN4 11
 
#define carSpeed 100
 
void forward(){ //car goes forward
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  Serial.println("go forward!");
}
 
void back(){ //car goes backwards
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  Serial.println("go back!");
}
 
void left(){ //goes left
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  Serial.println("go left!");
}
 
void right(){ //goes right
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW); 
  Serial.println("go right!");
} 
 
void stop(){ //power is shut off 
   digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
   digitalWrite(ENB, LOW);
   Serial.println("Stop!");
} 
 
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LT_R,INPUT);//takes input from all the sensors 
  pinMode(LT_M,INPUT);
  pinMode(LT_L,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
 
  if(LT_M){
    forward();
    while(LT_M);
  }
  else if(LT_R) { 
    right();    
    while(LT_R);                          
  }   
  else if(LT_L) {
    left(); 
    while(LT_L);
  }

  else if (LT_M && LT_R && !LT_L) {
  delay(500);
  right();   
  } 
  
  else if (LT_L && LT_R && !LT_R) {
   delay(500);
   left();    
    }
```

Comment: Your code is not complete. Sometime you use pins `ENA` and `ENB` with `digitalWrite` and sometimes with `analogWrite`. `#define LT_R !digitalRead(10)` is a macro definition: So, what is the meaning of `pinMode(LT_R,INPUT);` ;-)?  I wonder why parts of this program work.

Comment: PeterPaulKiefer is right with the pinMode statements. That will only configure either pin 0 or 1 as input. It cannot work as you wanted. Most likely you are profiting here from the fact, that at startup all the pins are already configured as inputs.

Answer (score 1):

First: Your code as 2 problems:

- As stated in the comments by PeterPaulKiefer, when you use

  ```
    pinMode(LT_R,INPUT);
  ```

  That is not working as intended by you. `LT_R` is defined at the top as

  ```
    #define LT_R !digitalRead(10)
  ```

  Thus the compiler will see

  ```
    pinMode(!digitalRead(10), INPUT);
  ```

  `digitalRead()` will return zero or one, thus you are configuring pin 0 or pin 1 here (depending on the state of the sensor at startup). Instead you need to directly use the pin number (10) or use another define for the pin number itself. Your code only works, because all the pins are configured as INPUT (tristate) at startup of the microcontroller, so that they don't break something with a wrong signal. You got lucky there.
- The last two else if statements are never executed:

  ```
    else if (LT_M && LT_R && !LT_L) {
        delay(500);
        right();   
    }
    else if (LT_L && LT_R && !LT_R) {
        delay(500);
        left();    
    }
  ```

  The conditions here will first evaluate `LT_M` (in the first statement) and `LT_L` (in the second statement) respectively. Only if these are true, the rest of the expression will be evaluated. But you already checked for both of them being true above. When they are, the following else if statements don't get executed (thats the logic of if else statements). And if they are false, the code will also not be executed.

  When you get to a 90° right corner, the middle and right sensor will trigger. Currently this will lead to the robot just keeping going forward.

So you need to change your code to actually check every every possible combination of the sensor states.

Also keep in mind, that a sharp corner needs way more turning, than a curve. Depending on the width of the line are the distance between your sensors, you might or might not be able to distinguish between those two cases. You should analyze, which sensor states you would have in which situations, write that down and then write code for every state. You could also put all sensor states into one single number, so that it is easier to check for it in the code. Something like this:

```
byte all_states = digitalRead(2) + 2*digitalRead(4) + 4*digitalRead(10);
```

Each combination will give you a unique number to work with. Effectively this stores the states of the sensors in one bit of the number each. Bit 0 is for pin 2, bit 1 is for pin 4 and bit 2 is for pin 10. You can also write this with bitwise operators:

```
byte all_states = digitalRead(2) | (digitalRead(4)<<1) | (digitalRead(10)<<2);
```

For example: If the right sensor is triggered, but not the others, you would get a binary number `0b00000100`, which is decimal `4`. If the left and the middle sensor are triggered, but not the right one, this results in `0b00000011`, which is decimal `3`. Then you could check with a switch statement:

```
switch(all_states){
    case 0: //No sensors triggered
        break;
    case 1: // Left sensor triggered
        break;
    case 2: // middle sensor triggerd
        break;
    case 3: // middle and left sensor triggered
        break;
    ...
}
```

You see how it works. The code for each case then goes inbetween of each case and break line.